# DbUpdateConcurrencyException trying to insert detail row after master row

Tags: entity-framework

Couldn't find and answer for whatever is happening to my code. I'm reading an XML from a web service and adding rows to my database, I'm using EF and after adding the header or master row, I get that exception when calling SaveChanges() on the detail row.

```
// master row insert
var result = 0;
using (var context = new XEntities())
{
    var masterRow = new TableName{
        x = someValue,
        ...
    };
    context.TableName.Add(masterRow);
    context.SaveChanges();
    result = masterRow.id;
}
return result;
```

So this insert has no issues, after returning that inserted row's id. I call a function to insert the detail with some parameters, including the parent id.

That's when I get that exception:

> DbUpdateConcurrencyException: Store update, insert, or delete
>   statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have
>   been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh
>   ObjectStateManager entries.

The code for the child row is exactly the same, of course with its own data. Any ideas how can I debug this exception? My best guess is the auto generated id on the master row, however, I'm logging the correct id (not 0) on the return statement after the first SaveChanges().

Edit:
I tried just now to insert my child row using context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(query, parameters) with the same data I used for entity framework and it works. But then why using context.Add(row) then SaveChanges() is not working? Typing queries is so from the 90's hahahaha

Comment: is your other DbSet configured the same way? what does your entry look like? what is the issued SQL query? it appears some concurrency token is altered by DBMS or EF and it does not expect it to do so.

Comment: I'm using the same code for both master and detail row, same connection string and entity. I also tried placing the detail code for the insert next to the master, after SaveChanges() using the same context, and I got the same error. It's killing me tbh lol. Again, I got it working with ExecuteSqlCommand, but why is not working with Linq